# Show titlebar separator when hovering? (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm creating an `NSWindow` with title bar (`.titled`) or tool bar and I tried to adopt a new look for macOS Big Sur.

For example, the titlebar effect of TextEdit is perfect:

[image: TextEdit]

As you can see above, when I hover above the title bar, the titlebar's separator shows with transition. Then the separator disappeared after the mouse left.

I found `NSTitlebarSeparatorStyle` in Apple Documentation:

[image: Apple Documentation]

The `automatic` style doesn't provide an auto changing separator.

So how can I achieve this? **Any good advise? :)**

---

Comment: You can pop into the debugger and check what values that particular window object is using... `e let $window = NSApplication.shared.orderedWindows.first(where: { $0.title = "Untitled" }`. Then you can poke around on `$window` all you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.automatic` style does provide the separator hover effect, but only when the window's content view consumes the full size of the window, that is, the `.fullSizeContentView` style mask.

So to have the effect you want, you will need to add `.fullSizeContentView` to your window's style mask:

```swift
window.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I've dropped this project for some times, your answer did fix this problem for me! :)